# How to break dependency on StreamReader's readLine() method in microsoft fakes unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, readline, microsoft-fakes

Here is my code in one of the method which I want to test:

```
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(myFile))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Equals("completed"))
                {
                    continue; //here it is getting called infinite times
                }

                if(line.Equals("processed"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

In my test method I have written below code with the help of shim:

```
            ShimStreamReader.ConstructorString = delegate (StreamReader @this, string @string)
            {
                var reader = new ShimStreamReader(@this);
                reader.ReadLine = () =>
                {
                    return "completed";
                };
            };
```

Now I dont want to pass the file. Instead I want to pass the stream of characters or string.
Above test code is calling and breaking the dependency of new StreamReader(myFile) as expected and entering into while loop.
As soon as it is entering it in while loop, sr.ReadLine() is returning "completed" all the time. So I'm stuck here. How would I stop here or how would I write the input string so that as soon as my first call return completed in second call of sr.ReadLine() it should return null, and then breaks the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You're more into a general coding question here rather than fakes.  All you need to do is add a flag and set it when you're ready to end the input.  This is the code I used

```
    private bool _lineSent = false;

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReaderTest()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimStreamReader.ConstructorString = (reader, s) =>
            {
                ShimStreamReader shimReader = new ShimStreamReader(reader);
                shimReader.ReadLine = () =>
                {
                    if (!_lineSent)
                    {
                        _lineSent = true;
                        return "completed";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            };

            ClassToTest testInstance = new ClassToTest();
            testInstance.ReadStream();
        }
    }
```

By the way, depending on your level and what you are trying to learn, you might want to look into dependency injection and using stubs rather then shims.  Shims are handy and nice, but for new development and code under your control, try to use stubs.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts Doobop. It was a late reply though but Thanks a lot DooBop. It might help someone as well. What I implemented was, created code to create one file with my expected inputs and passed it to reader and I was able to test my method then. Passing file inputs dint run into infinite loop. :) Cheers Thanks :)